# Getting bad substitution on Solaris 10 Bourne shell

Tags: shell

I need to extract part of the string before the last opt in the string:

```
NDS=/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt/abc
```

I want just the `/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/` part

I used `NDSHOME=${NDS%opt*}`
but I am getting bad substitution on Solaris 10, that is using the Bourne shell,
although this script works fine on Linux and AIX.
Can somebody find a solution to this??

Comment: The `/bin/sh` command on Solaris is a real (System V) Bourne Shell.  You should consider using Korn Shell (or even Bash) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris' /bin/sh is notoriously not Posix compatible.

You could try the following workaround with `sed`

```
NDSHOME=`echo "$NDS" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\<opt\>.*$/\1/'`
```

***Note:*** Normally I would use `$()` instead of backtics for command substitution, but I don't think those work on Solaris either.

**Edit**
Changed it so that `opt` will not match intra-word boundaries

```
$ echo $NDS
/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt/helicopter
$ echo "$NDS" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\<opt\>.*$/\1/'
/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/
```

Comment: You should write "Solaris /bin/sh is notoriously ...". Solaris itself is definitely POSIX compliant.

Comment: @jlliagre fair enough, changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `dirname` command prints all but the last level of the path name given as an argument.

```
$ NDS=/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt/abc
$ NDSHOME=`dirname $NDS`
$ echo $NDSHOME
/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt
```

(Add `export` as needed.)

**EDIT :**

The above doesn't work in this case.  The OP wants to remove all components of the path following the last `opt`, not just the last component.  I'll leave it here in case it's useful to someone else.

You *could* use `dirname` in a loop, stopping when the last component (as determined by `basename`) is `opt':

```
NDSHOME="$NDS"
while [ "`basename $NDSHOME`" != opt ] ; do
    NDSHOME="`dirname $NDSHOME`"
done
```

but that's more complex than it needs to be; sed is a better solution.

SiegeX's answer is good, but it treats `opt` as a string, not just as a path component.  For example, it will turn

```
/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt/helicopter
```

into

```
/opt/novell/opt/eDirectory/opt/helic
```

Try this:

```
NDSHOME=`echo "$NDS" | sed 's,\(.*\)/opt/.*$,\1,'`
```

(Note the use of `,` rather than `/` as a delimiter, so the `/` characters in the pattern don't have to be escaped.)

Comment: he'd need to `dirname` twice to get the output he wants

Comment: In this it is not sure that there will be only one or two levels after opt.. it can be any number of levels. So, we can't use dirname.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris is definitely POSIX (and several related standards like xpg4 and susv3) compliant but it also takes compatibility with older versions quite seriously.

The side effect is that when both these features conflict in some way, the affected commands are, by default, not POSIX compliant not to break legacy scripts.

Should you want POSIX compatibility and have no legacy script issues, just set your PATH like this:

```
PATH=/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:$PATH
```

and set your login shell to `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`

Alternatively, if you do not need strict compliance, you might just use `/bin/ksh` as your default shell.

With Solaris 10 and older, you shouldn't really use `/bin/sh` at all in new scripts.

For reference, here is the Solaris 10 [standards](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5175/standards-5/index.html) manual page and the one for Solaris 11 is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1474/standards-5.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bourne-Again shell instead.

Comment: we don't have an option to change the shell we have to use bourne shell only.

Comment: Then you're SOL. Use `sed` or the like instead.